# Efficiently multi-threading a process that returns a value 44100 times a second

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
    public float[] Next(int samples)
    {
        float[] result = new float[samples];
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
            result[i] = 0;
        foreach (var b in boards)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
                result[i] += b.Next();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This function is called 44100 times a second and takes practically all processing power. The `board.Next()` functions run completely independently of each other so I'm thinking there should be a way of multi-threading this.

I've tried the following:

```
    public float[] Next(int samples)
    {
        float[] result = new float[samples];
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
            result[i] = 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(boards, b =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
                result[i] += b.Next();
        });
        return result;
    }
```

But that only made it worse.

Is there a way to multi-thread this process without enormous threading overhead?

There are often less than 10 boards. Never more than 100.

The `board.Next()` method is not the same as the calling method. That is, the class that defines this `Next()` is not the same class as `board`.

**Solved:**

Kind of, I think...

I replaced this:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(boards, b =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
            result[i] += b.Next();
    });
```

With this:

```
    Parallel.ForEach(boards, b =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
        {
            var next = b.Next();
            lock (result)
                result[i] += next;
        }
    });
```

Apparently, C# automatically locked result when it was added to. This I had expected. What I hadn't expected was that it did so *before evaluating the right-hand side*. So by splitting the addition and the call to Next() into separate statements, Next() was allowed to be called in parallel.

Comment: What does b.Next() do? Is there enough work in it? Did you profile your code?

Comment: @gdir I'm not entirely sure I understand your question. When I profile b.Next() uses more than 80% of the CPU.

Comment: @FCin b.Next() and the shown method are different methods. I'll change the question to make that clear.

Comment: Hmm, 44100 is a standard audio sampling *bitrate*.  Surely you ought to be able to sample more than 1 bit at a time.  Or you are trying to make it 16 or 32 times faster than it needs to be.  Or you ought to read many more values at a time, such boards invariably have a buffer to make data retrieval practical.  Talk with the vendor/manufacturer about it.

Comment: Spawning multiple threads 44100 times a second is surely a bad idea, the overhead will negate any possible gains.

Comment: Multi-threading causes some overhead. If there's not enough work inside a single call to b.Next(), the overhead will add more time than multi-threading of b.Next() will safe. b.Next() should be big enough to benefit from multi-threading.

Comment: The multithreaded version of your method is not thread safe! You need to lock the variable `result` when adding.

Comment: @HansPassant The library I'm using does use a buffer and I've now grouped my samples so I don't need to create as many new threads. This helps immensely, but it's still far worse than the unthreaded version.

Comment: The total amount of work done inside the `Parallel.ForEach` must be high enough. Can you increase `samples` value and instead call the method less times?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov This turned out to be the problem. Further description in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, you make bigger mistakes.

44100 is not a particularly high number for a loop. But you ahve beginner mistakes:

> float[] result = new float[samples];

This is 44100 allocations which may or may not be needed. Standard for this type if function is that the controlling functions passes in an array and says how many samples it wants (optionally, upt to the length of the array) and you return not the array but the number of samples actually delivered (becuse there may be less).

And before considering b.next in a parallel foreach, I would measure it and put the measuring numbers in here - because most of the time this makes little sense.

This way you can avoid the allocation - and believe me, you do not wan to allocate 44100 arrays per second. That is close to suicide.